# Coldfusion OpenXml Error: Could not load file or assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml'

Tags: c#, .net, coldfusion, openxml

I am .net coder and I am really really new to ColdFusion. I wrote a .dll library which automatically generates an invoice. I needed to use the library from a ColdFusion application. I have successfully loaded the classes in my library as coldfusion objects as I can call the methods. However, there is one method in my class which uses WordprocessingDocument which is a class of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging. I am actually getting this error :

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.5.5631.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name:
>   'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.5.5631.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'    at
>   InvoiceLibrary.DocumentHandler.ConvertDocumentToDOCX(String file)
>   at InvoiceLibrary.DocumentHandler.ProcessDocument()

I have imported the DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll so is the WindowsBase.dll files

```
<cfObject type=".NET" name="WordprocessingDocument"
     class="DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument" 
     assembly="C:\Users\mydocs\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\InvoiceGenerator\InvoiceLibrary\bin\Release\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll,C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\WindowsBase.dll">
```

I need your guidance to what am I doing wrong or what am I missing here?

Comment: ooh thanks to that Leigh! Yeah, that looks a lot better now :)

Comment: Welcome :) Unfortunately, I do not have an answer, but did you check the jnbridge (used for .net interop) logs? See `{cf_install}/jnbridge/error.log`. *Sometimes* that log contain additional details about .net errors.

Comment: No, I have not yet. I'll try it now. I've been stuck on this problem for quite a while now. Sucks balls! I could call methods in .dll library successfully, but this particular method which implements WordprocessingDocument class is where it fails. I'm sure I've included all dependencies. Could it be a class loader issue? Anyways, Thank you for your suggestion, I'll check right away

Comment: Did you include all of the dependencies with *every* createObject call? Omitting a few might cause that problem. *Could it be a class loader issue* Possibly, that is sometimes the cause of "method not found .." errors, but it is hard to say.

Comment: If you are feeling adventurous, you might try [generating the proxies yourself](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec13e1a-7ffd.html) with built in tools in `\jnbridge` directory. Also, in case it is relevant what is your full CF version? Check the CF Admin screen or use `<cfdump var="#server.coldfusion#">`

Comment: Right click on the DLL in your binary folder and look at the Details tab. Make sure the version of the file matches your reference Version=2.5.5631.0. Sometimes if the version of the assemblies are different, you can get this error.

Comment: It seems that your computer hasn't installed OpenXmlSDK.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool like [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to make sure you are copying all of the required linked dlls that DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll is using.  Also do not forget to copy this file with your output.